Excel Matrix - Formula or Function to Determine Upper and Lower Triangular Sums
I am trying to write an Excel formula(s) that would replicate the upper.tri, lower.tri and diag matrix functions in R.
In Excel the upper (right) sum - the green area in this example would be where the column number is greater than the row number and vice-versa for the orange area.
The yellow cells (the diagonal) are where the row number is equal to the column number.
I can't find any built-in matrix function in Excel for this calculation though given there are ROW(), COLUMN() and SUMIF() functions I am sure there must be some elegant way to do it with a combination of these without writing VBA code. So the question basically is how do I determine the sum of a range of cells based on the values of their row and column references?
Please note. I do not want to accomplish this via conditional formatting or applying filters by color. This small example is just for illustrative purposes.
The desired sums are 71.85% upper, 20.6 lower, 7.55 diagonal.   

For the Upper.tri:
=LET(_rg,D1:H5,SUM((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_rg))<SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_rg)))*_rg))

diagonal
=LET(_rg,D1:H5,SUM((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_rg))=SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_rg)))*_rg))

Lower
=LET(_rg,D1:H5,SUM((SEQUENCE(ROWS(_rg))>SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_rg)))*_rg))



Just for fun, older versions:
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(D1:H5)))<COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,COLUMNS(D1:H5))))*D1:H5)
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(D1:H5)))=COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,COLUMNS(D1:H5))))*D1:H5)
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(D1:H5)))>COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,COLUMNS(D1:H5))))*D1:H5)



Thank you Scott. Great answer though are you able to briefly clarify how the formula works?  It looks like it's defining a range then building arrays of the row and column values in that range with SEQUENCE and summing them?  I wasn't familiar with this function.  Can you explain what is happening in the last part of the formula with the multiplication operator *_rg?  I have to confess I'm lost at this point.

@user3500717 just try to evaluate the formula by selecting the cell and then goto Formulas Tab, click on Evaluate, since LAMBDA() is not involved in the above formulas the evaluate would show you all the steps one by one. That is how you will get to know how these formulas works.

Thanks I have gone through the evaluation steps though I am still unclear exactly what the last step is doing.

@user3500717 do one thing, write down all the steps in each of its own cell one by one to break and understand. I dont think it is too difficult to understand. First in cell A10 write =D1:H5 then in another cell, write =ROWS(A10#) since its an array, the cell A10 accompanies with an # wrapped within ROWS() function to give the number of rows involved which is 5 similarly do it for the Columns by =COLUMNS(A10#) which gives 5 now both of these when wrapped within SEQUENCE() will give a vertical and horizontal array. compare the row wise with column to get an array of TRUE

and FALSE . lastly do a matrix multiplication with the actual array D1:H5 with the TRUE and FALSE returned. finally sum these to get the output. try it.

I see what's happening now.  It's multiplying a matrix of True or False elements i.e 1s or 0s by the elements in the original matrix to come up with the totals.

Yup a 2D array of TRUE and FALSE when multiplied with D1:H5 returns an array again and lastly sum it

Here is a animated video watch to understand more clearly also hope your query is resolved now, please ensure to accept the answer by ticking the checkmark beside it

Just a quick shout out for MAKEARRAY as an alternative to two SEQUENCES. eg =LET(arr,D1:H5,d,ROWS(arr),SUM(arr * MAKEARRAY(d,d,LAMBDA(r,c,N(c>r))))) which assumes a square matrix.
